# Problem with opacity after saving as PNG-8 or GIF from Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, gif

I am a web developer and I have a problem with the opacity of a photo after saving as a PNG or GIF. I have an image with a transparent background with a layer with less than 1% opacity. After saving it loses the opacity and shows a solid background.

Below is how my image appears before and after saving:

[image]

I want something like the upper image but the result is like the lower image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIF and PNG-8<sup>*</sup> don't support alpha transparency. Each pixel either needs to be completely transparent or opaque, no partial transparency—so your <1% opacity won't work.

You have a few options:

1. Use PNG-24, which supports full alpha transparency. If you need to you can then use a third party tool (such as [CompressPNG](http://compresspng.com/) or [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)) to convert to PNG-8 and retain the alpha transparency.
2. Make the areas completely transparent. You can either modify your original artwork or map a color to transparency in the Save for Web dialog (as seen in [this Q&A](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/76045/52050)).
3. If you are using a recent version of Photoshop (CC) you can use the new export (File → Export → Export As), which (as far as I know, I don't actually have CC to check)does support full alpha transparency with PNG-8.

<sup>*</sup> This isn't a limitation in the PNG format but Photoshop's Save for Web feature.

Comment: Here's [another](http://way2enjoy.com/compress-png) good png/jpg compressor, plus it allows you process 50 files at once.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to (instead of "saving" it) exporting your graphics in Photoshop as a 32-bit PNG (standard if you export with the tick in the box for PNG-transparency) which will make the transparency "true" making it show how you intended in more/all apps that support transparency/alpha channels. For instance this changes the results for the iOS13/Photos app! :) You can read more about this here: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/export-artboards-layers.html